# lmer error: Hessian is numerically singular

Tags: r, lme4

in the quest of finding the best model for one of my studies (which I took over from another person), R, unfortunately, gives me an error message for my preferred option.

Just a short info what the experiment is about: 3 Species, each in one separate block, with 4 treatments per block (of which 3 of interest) and 5 replicates each. One observation (total biomass yield) of interest for the model. I think (blame me if not, I am not a statistician) it is a generalised complete block design since I expect an interaction between block (species) and treatment. Due to skew data distribution, I sqrt transformed my dependent variable.

The dataset (only 43 observations) can be found at the end of this post

Here is the model that gives the error:

```
 a1<-lmer(sqrt(Yield)~Cuts*Species+Cuts+TN.Yield+0+(1|Species), data=all)
```

And that is the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
```

While the others (those I don't like) work fine:

```
b1<-lmer(sqrt(Yield)~Cuts+TN.Yield+0+(1|Species), data=all, na.action = na.omit)
c1<-lmer(sqrt(Yield)~Cuts+0+(1|Species),data=all)
d1<-lmer(sqrt(Yield)~Cuts * TN.Yield * Species + 0 + (1 | Species),data=all)
```

However, model a1 still seems to give me an output:

```
                        Dependent variable:     
                    -----------------------------
                             sqrt(Yield)         
-------------------------------------------------
Cuts0                         0.686***           
                              p = 0.000          
Cuts2                         0.638***           
                              p = 0.000          
Cuts5                         0.380***           
                              p = 0.000          
SpeciesRCG                     -0.061            
                              p = 0.272          
SpeciesTF                      -0.029            
                              p = 0.605          
TN.Yield                      0.403***           
                              p = 0.000          
Cuts2:SpeciesRCG               -0.067            
                              p = 0.404          
Cuts5:SpeciesRCG                0.073            
                              p = 0.364          
Cuts2:SpeciesTF                -0.127            
                              p = 0.103          
Cuts5:SpeciesTF                 0.081            
                              p = 0.297          
-------------------------------------------------
Observations                     43              
Log Likelihood                 26.665            
Akaike Inf. Crit.              -29.330           
Bayesian Inf. Crit.            -8.195            
=================================================
Note:               *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001
```

Would anyone like to explain what the error means (and how to please the code)? I get the idea that it, unfortunately, might be a more substantial problem.

Cheers, Claudia

Data:

```
   Blok Treatment Species Week     Pot Cuts Days Yield       TC TN.Yield   Yield.day  Yield140   DM
1     1     0 cut      FL   45  Hyk0.1    0  238  0.72 41.40000 0.690816 0.003025210 0.4235294 1.89
2     1     0 cut      FL   45  Hyk0.2    0  238  0.67 41.81667 0.718080 0.002815126 0.3941176 1.69
3     1     0 cut      FL   45  Hyk0.3    0  238  1.45 44.06333 1.076332 0.006092437 0.8529412 3.40
4     1     0 cut      FL   45  Hyk0.4    0  238  1.62 43.14333 1.139088 0.006806723 0.9529412 3.90
5     1     0 cut      FL   45  Hyk0.5    0  238  1.04 42.54333 0.681966 0.004369748 0.6117647 2.54
6     1     2 cut      FL   37  Hyk2.1    2  182  0.88 43.45250 0.965549 0.004835165 0.6769231 2.02
7     1     2 cut      FL   37  Hyk2.2    2  182  1.24 43.47000 1.049044 0.006813187 0.9538462 2.87
8     1     2 cut      FL   37  Hyk2.3    2  182  1.21 43.58750 1.036352 0.006648352 0.9307692 2.81
9     1     2 cut      FL   37  Hyk2.4    2  182  0.56 44.16500 0.532143 0.003076923 0.4307692 1.24
10    1     2 cut      FL   37  Hyk2.5    2  182  1.30 43.69750 1.016196 0.007142857 1.0000000 2.99
11    1     5 cut      FL   44  Hyk5.1    5  231  0.23 42.46000 0.482065 0.000995671 0.1393939 0.56
12    1     5 cut      FL   44  Hyk5.2    5  231  0.48 43.15000 0.748596 0.002077922 0.2909091 1.14
13    1     5 cut      FL   44  Hyk5.3    5  231  0.40 42.62571 0.634108 0.001731602 0.2424242 0.97
14    1     5 cut      FL   44  Hyk5.4    5  231  0.60 42.09000 0.780787 0.002597403 0.3636364 1.43
15    1     5 cut      FL   44  Hyk5.5    5  231  0.33 43.46000 0.470763 0.001428571 0.2000000 0.79
16    3     0 cut      TF   45 Kora0.1    0  238  0.64 42.39333 0.575980 0.002689076 0.3764706 1.58
17    3     0 cut      TF   45 Kora0.2    0  238  1.36 42.84667 0.845687 0.005714286 0.8000000 3.30
18    3     0 cut      TF   45 Kora0.3    0  238  0.76 41.85667 0.937703 0.003193277 0.4470588 1.89
19    3     0 cut      TF   45 Kora0.4    0  238  0.94 42.53333 0.594815 0.003949580 0.5529412 2.37
20    3     0 cut      TF   45 Kora0.5    0  238  0.97 43.54333 0.785654 0.004075630 0.5705882 2.30
21    3     2 cut      TF   37 Kora2.1    2  182  0.27 43.54750 0.207677 0.001483516 0.2076923 0.62
22    3     2 cut      TF   37 Kora2.2    2  182  0.39 43.56250 0.281726 0.002142857 0.3000000 0.92
23    3     2 cut      TF   37 Kora2.3    2  182  0.45 43.07750 0.552136 0.002472527 0.3461538 1.07
24    3     2 cut      TF   37 Kora2.4    2  182  0.73 42.23500 0.719066 0.004010989 0.5615385 1.84
25    3     2 cut      TF   37 Kora2.5    2  182  0.82 43.49750 1.129846 0.004505495 0.6307692 1.92
26    3     5 cut      TF   44 Kora5.1    5  231  0.43 42.76714 0.436980 0.001861472 0.2606061 1.09
27    3     5 cut      TF   44 Kora5.2    5  231  0.32 42.60714 0.488435 0.001385281 0.1939394 0.85
28    3     5 cut      TF   44 Kora5.3    5  231  0.48 42.69143 0.788342 0.002077922 0.2909091 1.20
29    3     5 cut      TF   44 Kora5.4    5  231  0.73 43.34286 0.923832 0.003160173 0.4424242 1.74
30    3     5 cut      TF   44 Kora5.5    5  231  0.60 43.25857 0.798059 0.002597403 0.3636364 1.40
31    2     0 cut     RCG   45  RCG0.1    0  238  0.85 43.91000 0.732087 0.003571429 0.5000000 1.99
32    2     0 cut     RCG   45  RCG0.2    0  238  0.99 44.15000 0.810263 0.004159664 0.5823529 2.29
33    2     0 cut     RCG   45  RCG0.3    0  238  1.50 44.74000 1.704005 0.006302521 0.8823529 3.45
34    2     0 cut     RCG   45  RCG0.4    0  238  0.99 42.47000 0.708496 0.004159664 0.5823529 2.28
35    2     0 cut     RCG   45  RCG0.5    0  238  0.71 41.15667 0.644570 0.002983193 0.4176471 1.70
36    2     2 cut     RCG   37  RCG2.1    2  182  0.48 45.09000 0.461009 0.002637363 0.3692308 1.06
37    2     2 cut     RCG   37  RCG2.3    2  182  0.84 44.78750 1.095394 0.004615385 0.6461538 1.90
38    2     2 cut     RCG   37  RCG2.4    2  182  0.66 44.92500 0.844105 0.003626374 0.5076923 1.46
39    2     2 cut     RCG   37  RCG2.5    2  182  0.61 45.00250 0.486282 0.003351648 0.4692308 1.36
40    2     5 cut     RCG   44  RCG5.2    5  231  0.52 43.78714 0.682854 0.002251082 0.3151515 1.22
41    2     5 cut     RCG   44  RCG5.3    5  231  0.76 44.75429 1.399784 0.003290043 0.4606061 1.72
42    2     5 cut     RCG   44  RCG5.4    5  231  0.52 43.85286 0.727006 0.002251082 0.3151515 1.21
43    2     5 cut     RCG   44  RCG5.5    5  231  0.43 42.87429 0.672898 0.001861472 0.2606061 1.07
```

Comment: I can't replicate an error with `a1`. What version of `lme4` and R are you using? Is it possible to use `dput` to give us `all` as it enters the function, please? I've tried using the google sheet but possibly something has changed in translation eg classes. My output for `a1` is different too eg `Cuts0` has an effect of `0.8026` for me, not `0.686`. Also, what is the error message you receive?

Comment: Hej Jonny, I apologise for forgetting the error - that's what happens when you try to work at home while also having 4 kids at home because schools are closed :/ However, I've added the error to my question and the input data. Cheers, Claudia

Comment: R 4.0.2, lme4 1.1-23